# Can i manage ActiveMQ workers without demonization?

Tags: activemq-classic, worker, high-load

I lookup information about workers in Gearman, ZeroMQ and RabbitMQ and i find, that best practice is using something like Supervisor. I google for ActiveMQ but can't find information about workers managing. Is it the same, or ActiveMQ can start, kill, restart and increase number of workers by himself?

Comment: You should probably elaborate a bit more on your actual question. Are you talking about starting multiple brokers or is it about auto-scaling of consumer threads?

Comment: I thing a already found answer, that ActiveMQ can't handle consumers and i must use supervisord for example.